# Highstock how to hide zeros in the data

Tags: highcharts

In this chart the data is imported from a csv file and can´t be changed.

```
data: {
    googleSpreadsheetKey: '1TlXkg_COywLso2dcUhkT79L8IEJrLC8Mdb-leXVFgiM',
    startColumn: 0,
    endColumn: 1,
    startRow: 0,
    endRow: 4310
}
```

Missing values are expressed as zeros and should not be plotted: https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/03ugzb1j/1/

How can I handle this (for example by replacing zeros by nulls)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use data.complete event to edit your data after you fetch it: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.complete

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uty6e380/

```
data: {
        googleSpreadsheetKey: '1TlXkg_COywLso2dcUhkT79L8IEJrLC8Mdb-leXVFgiM',
        startColumn: 0,
        endColumn: 1,
        startRow: 0,
        endRow: 4310,
        complete: function(options) {
            options.series[0].data.forEach(point => {
                if (point[1] === 0) {
                    point[1] = null;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```